# Trigger after update on parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, triggers

Is there a way to create a trigger after update on parse.com? For example, I have column quantity and total quantity. Current total quantity that I have is 50. When I update the column quantity to 5, the total quantity is updated to 55. It is similar like MYSQL or Oracle trigger.

Comment: Yes.  Not similar to mysql or oracle trigger, but you can run code before and after significant db events, for example: https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html#methods_afterSave

Comment: @danh ohhh ok thanks,, but what about the code? is it same?

Comment: You write the code in JavaScript. The docs explain it pretty well.

Comment: @danh actually i want to calculate the total point for soccer game, if the A team win and B team lose, the point for A team will added by 3 points and if they drew both of team got 1 point each. can i do something like this in parse.com? i'm still new to this thing..

Comment: Yes, that's just the sort of thing you can do.

Comment: @danh ok thanks,, really appreciate it..